# mismatched input ''.'' in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I am new to ANTLR4 and my grammar contains a rule `STRING: '\'' (~'\'' | '.' | '\\\'')* '\'' ;`, but when I try to parse something containing `'.'` I obtain the error `mismatched input ''.'' expecting {'(', ID, STRING}`. Shouldn't the expected alternative STRING be able to parse my `'.'`?

This problem only happens if the character is a dot. I tried modifying my STRING rules or making a rule that only parse `'.'` but parsing a dot between quotes doesn't seems possible from my point of view.

EDIT: as requested here is my grammar

```
grammar Antlr4Grammar;

grammarFile: 'grammar' grammarName=ID ';' (grammarRules+=rules)* baseRules* EOF;

rules: name=ID ':' ((body=ruleBody) | (children+=ID)) ('|' children+=ID)* ';';


ruleBody: (bodies+=terminalRuleBody)+ 'EOF'?;

terminalRuleBody:
  body=terminalRuleBody (op=operator)
  | parentRuleBody
  | stringRuleBody
  | affectRuleBody 
  ;

starOperator: '*';
          
plusOperator: '+';

questionMarkOperator: '?';

operator: starOperator | plusOperator | questionMarkOperator;

parentRuleBody:
    '(' body=ruleBody ')';

stringRuleBody:
    body=STRING ;

affectRuleBody:
    name=ID op=affectOp value=rOperand;

rOperand:
    val=ID | val='INT' | val='FLOAT' | val='CHAR' | val='STRING' | val='ID' ;

affectOp: eqOp | plusEqOp;

eqOp: '=';

plusEqOp: '+=';

baseRules:
    intBaseRule | floatBaseRule | charBaseRule | stringBaseRule | idBaseRule | wsBaseRule;

intBaseRule: 'INT' ':' '\'-\'?[0-9]+' ';';

floatBaseRule: 'FLOAT' ':' '\'-\'?[0-9]+' '\'.\'' + '[0-9]*' ';' ;

charBaseRule: 'CHAR' ':' '\'\\\'\'' '(\'\\\\\'|.)' '\'\\\'\'' ';' ;

stringBaseRule: 'STRING' ':' '\'"\'' '(\'\\\\\'|.)*?' '\'"\'' ';';

idBaseRule: 'ID' ':' '[a-zA-Z_]' '[a-zA-Z_0-9]*' ';' ;

wsBaseRule: 'WS' ':' '[ \\t\\r\\n]' '->' 'skip' ';' ;

ID: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
STRING: '\'' (~'\'' | '.' | '\\\'')* '\'' ;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

and here is the program I try to parse

```
grammar MiniJava;


program: mainClass=mainClass ( classDecl+=classDeclaration )*;

mainClass: 'class' name=ID '{' 'public' 'static' 'void' 'main' '(' 'String' '[' ']' argName=ID ')' '{' body=statement '}' '}';

classDeclaration: 'class' name=ID ('extends' parentClass=ID)? '{' (varDecl+=varDeclaration)* (methodDecl+=methodDeclaration)* '}';

varDeclaration: varType=type varName=ID ';';

methodDeclaration: 'public' returnType=type methodName=ID '(' (argType+=type argName+=ID (',' argType+=type argName+=ID)* )? ')' '{' (varDecl+=varDeclaration)* (body+=Statement)* 'return' returnExpr=expression ';' '}';

type: intArrayType | booleanType | intType | idType;

intArrayType: 'int' '[' ']';

booleanType: 'boolean';

intType: 'int';

idType: typeName=ID;

statement: compoundStatement | ifStatement | whileStatement | printStatement | affectStatement | affectArrayStatement;

compoundStatement: '{' (body+=statement)* '}';

ifStatement: 'if' '(' cond=expression ')' thenPart=statement 'else' elsePart=statement;

whileStatement: 'while' '(' cond=expression ')' body=statement;

printStatement: 'System.out.println' '(' printExpr=expression ')' ';';

affectStatement: lValue=ID '=' rValue=expression ';';

affectArrayStatement: array=ID '[' index=expression ']' '=' value=expression ';' ;

expression: binOpExpr;

binOpExpr: loperand=expression op=operator roperand=postfixExpression | postfixExpression;

operator: andOperator | lessThanOperator | plusOperator | minusOperator | multOperator;

andOperator: '&&';

lessThanOperator: '<';

plusOperator: '+';

minusOperator: '-';

multOperator: '*';

postfixExpression: baseExpr=unaryExpression operator=postfixOperator ;

postfixOperator: arrayIndexOperation | lengthOperation | methodCallOperation;

arrayIndexOperation:  '[' index=expression ']';

lengthOperation: '.' 'length';

methodCallOperation: '.' methodName=ID '(' (args+=expression (',' args+=expression)*)? ')';

unaryExpression: constIntExpression | trueExpression | falseExpression | varExpression | thisExpression | newExpression | notExpression | parentExpression;

constIntExpression: value=INT;

trueExpression: 'true';

falseExpression: 'false';

varExpression: varName=ID;

thisExpression: 'this';

newExpression: newClassExpression | newArrayExpression;

newClassExpression: 'new' name=ID '(' ')';
newArrayExpression: 'new' 'int' '[' size=expression ']';


notExpression: '!' baseExpr=expression;

parentExpression: '(' baseExpr=expression ')';

INT: '-'?[0-9]+;
FLOAT: '-'?[0-9]+ '.' [0-9]*;
CHAR: '\'' ('\\'|.) '\'';
STRING: '"' ('\\'|.)*? '"';
ID: [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
WS: [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;
```

I didn't give it at first because I was worried it was a little confusing as my grammar represents a subset of the antlr4 grammar.

Comment: That is impossible to tell by just looking at the single `STRING` rule. Please post you entire grammar (or enough so that the error can be reproduced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be careful when mixing literal tokens in a parser rule (the `'literal'` in my example) and lexer rules that might also match what you defined as literal tokens (the `ID` rule below):

```
parse
 : 'literal' ID
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z]+
 ;
```

If you try to let the input `"literal literal"` be parsed by the `parse` rule, it will not work, even though the input `"literal"` *could* be matched by the `ID` rule.

This is because ANTLR will translate my example as follows:

```
parse
 : T__0 ID
 ;

T__0
 : 'literal'
 ;

ID
 : [a-zA-Z]+
 ;
```

And given that ANTLR will always create a single token for a particular input, it will always tokenise `"literal"` as a `T__0` token; it will never become an `ID` token.

This is what is happening in your grammar as well. In your `floatBaseRule`, you have defined the literal token `'\'.\''` that your `stringRuleBody` is trying to match as a `STRING` (but cannot do so):

```
floatBaseRule. : 'FLOAT' ':' '\'-\'?[0-9]+' '\'.\''+ '[0-9]*' ';' ;
stringRuleBody : STRING ;
```

You either need to change `'\'.\''` into `stringRuleBody`:

```
floatBaseRule. : 'FLOAT' ':' '\'-\'?[0-9]+' stringRuleBody+ '[0-9]*' ';' ;
stringRuleBody : STRING ;
```

or let `stringRuleBody` also match the literal `'\'.\''`:

```
floatBaseRule. : 'FLOAT' ':' '\'-\'?[0-9]+' '\'.\''+ '[0-9]*' ';' ;
stringRuleBody : STRING | '\'.\'';
```

IMO, the best is to remove all these `'...'` literal tokens from all your parser rules and move them into their own lexer rules.

Also note that there is an ANTLR4 grammar that can parse itself: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/antlr/antlr4

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. If something can match two different rules, it will always be treated as the first one defined. Thanks, it works now! 
Thank you for the repository with antlr4 grammars. I will keep doing my own grammars to learn more about antlr, but it can be useful.

Comment: "If something can match two different rules, it will always be treated as the first one defined", yes, that is correct. And the inline lexer rules will be placed before the lexer rules.